# Running linux bash command from cakephp

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, cakephp-2.0

Right now I working on a project using CakePHP and I want to run a bash shell script via the same. I read the documentation on [console and shells](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) but I am unable to link it with the bash shell script. Something like "./MyShellScript" or "ls -l" on the terminal through cake php's console would be enough to run a bash shell script. Or, any plugin for the same! Also, if there is another way then that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the output of the bashscript, use [system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

```
system ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )
```

if not, use [exec](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
 exec( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can execute any bash command with exec() function:

```
exec("sh myBashScript.sh",$output);
```

just make sure your apache user has necessary permission to execute that file.